# kivyでインスタンス?をまたいで変数代入ができない

Tags: python, python2, kivy

kivyで簡単なプログラムを試しに作っていたんですが
題にあるよう、インスタンス?をまたいでの変数代入を行うとエラーがおきます

```
TypeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

```py
class pullscreen(Screen):
    def clicked(self):
        x = np.random.randint(1,10,1)
        if x == 5:
            result.ids["res"].text = "1"
        elif x % 2 == 0:
            result.ids["res"].text = "2"
        else:
            result.ids["res"].text = "3"
        sm.current = "ans"

class result(Screen):
    def back(self):
        sm.current = "pull"
```

self.idsとするとそのインスタンス内の変数を指定するため望む結果が得られません。
どうすれば良いのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします

pyファイル

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics", "resizable", False)
Config.set("graphics", "width", 640)
Config.set("graphics", "height", 480)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import numpy as np

sm = ScreenManager()

class pullscreen(Screen):
    def clicked(self):
        x = np.random.randint(1,10,1)
        if x == 5:
            result.ids["res"].text = "1"
        elif x % 2 == 0:
            result.ids["res"].text = "2"
        else:
            result.ids["res"].text = "3"
        sm.current = "ans"

class result(Screen):
    def back(self):
        sm.current = "pull"


class Amidakuji(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(pullscreen(name = "pull"))
        sm.add_widget(result(name = "ans"))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Amidakuji().run()
```

kvファイル

```
<PaddingBoxLayout@BoxLayout>:
    padding: 20

<pullscreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.9,0.9,0.9,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: "Amidakuji"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            font_size: 32

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "uranau"
                on_press: root.clicked()

<result>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.9,0.9,0.9,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: "result"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            font_size: 32

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                id: res

            Button:
                text: "mo-ikkai, uranau"
                on_press: root.back()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resultは

```
class result(Screen):
```

とあるのでクラスであってインスタンスではありません。
kivyは分かりませんけど、

```
        sm.add_widget(result(name = "ans"))
```

とありますから、「result(name = "ans")」の戻り値（おそらくresultのインスタンス）を参照すべきであって、resultクラスそのものを参照したために発生したエラーなのでしょう。

解決策としてインスタンスをグローバルに参照できるようにする手もありますが、
ScreenManagerのメソッドにget_screen(name)というメソッドがあるようなので、

```
    def clicked(self):
        x = np.random.randint(1,10,1)
        ans = sm.get_screen("ans")
        if x == 5:
            ans.ids["res"].text = "1"
              :
```

とでもしてみるとどうでしょうか？

---

追記
グローバル化とはAmidakuji#buildで生成したインスタンスをpullscreen#clickedで参照したいので、smと同じく、どちらからでも参照できるようにしておくための方法です。
具体的には下記の様になると思います。

```
    :
import numpy as np

sm = ScreenManager()
result_ans = result(name = "ans")

class pullscreen(Screen):
    :

    :
class Amidakuji(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(pullscreen(name = "pull"))
        sm.add_widget(result_ans)
        return sm
    :
```

このようにして、あらかじめインスタンスを作っておきます。
この場合clickedではresult_ansを使います。
ただ、kivyの作法を知らないので、もしかしたらAmidakuji#build内でインスタンスを作るべきかもしれません。
その場合はこんな感じになるかもしれません。

```
    :
import numpy as np

sm = ScreenManager()
result_ans = None

class pullscreen(Screen):
    :

    :
class Amidakuji(App):
    def build(self):
        global result_ans
        sm.add_widget(pullscreen(name = "pull"))
        result_ans = result(name = "ans")
        sm.add_widget(result_ans)
        return sm
    :
```

こちらでは、result_ansを通してメソッドで作ったインスタンスにアクセスします。
もちろんclickedでもresult_ansを使います。

sm.get_screen("ans")は単純にsm.add_widget()で登録したもののうち、name="ans"のもの、つまりresult(name = "ans")を得るメソッドです。
ここにids以下の中身があるわけなので。

いずれも登録する／したresult(name = "ans")をどうやって手に入れるかという話です。
今回の場合、ScreenManagerに、実際に登録されているScreenインスタンスを得る手段であるget_screenが用意されているわけなので、それを使うのが一番素直な方法だと思います。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。よろしければもう少し詳しく教えてもらえませんか？インスタンスのグローバル化やget_screen(name)がちょっと理解できません。すいません

Comment: コメント部分について追記してみました。

Comment: なんとなく理解できました！ありがとうございます！！